# How to bind a click event to the document so that it fires only when no object is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I would like an event to fire whenever something other than a DOM element is clicked, and a separate event when an image is clicked.

Right now I have:

```
$( document ).click( function() { /*do whatev*/ } );
```

and in another place:

```
$( "img" ).click( function( e ) { 
  e.stopPropagation();
  /*do whatev*/
} );
```

it does not work. both events are fired. any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and concise:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
  if (jQuery(event.target).is('img'))
  {
    alert('img');
  }
  else
  {
    // Reject event
    return false;
  }
});
```

If the user clicks on an img element 'img' is alerted, otherwise the click event is stopped.

Comment: Wouldn't that setup be the same as, from OP's question, `$("img").click(function(e) {e.stopPropagation();/*code here*/});` but your way adds a ton more click listeners to the DOM...?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but doesn't adding a click event handler to the document attach it *just* to the document and not to *every* DOM descendant node?

Comment: this works. However, when I tried .not('img') and .is('not(img)') it does not ...

Comment: In my previous comment I meant `.is(':not(img)')`!

Comment: @ncuesta oh yes i made a typo; there we are, now my code is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
$('*').click(function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).is('img')) alert('img');
    else if($(this).is('div')) alert('div');
    else alert('something else');
});
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/U2Szn/ ?

Comment: I think that he will also need to assign an ID to the img, because I doubt that will be the only one in the page.

Comment: Hi Andy. Generally, it is better to post your code here as well. Examples are always good, but posts should consist of the actual code, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but just `img` isn't enough.  It could be triggering from the img container.  I think you'd need a selector like `$('p,div,img,a,input,textarea,span,ul,ol,dl,li,dd,dt,table,tr,td')` and any other tag you can think of to pull it off.  This might have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event to fire when the `html` and/or `body` is clicked or an `img` is clicked something like this should work: **[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/upuba3/2/edit)**

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('html')){
    alert('this is the html element');
  }else if($(e.target).is('body')){
    alert('this is the body element');
  }
});
$("img").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('img')
});​
```